# How to install and use mmlspark on a local machine with Conda Python?

Tags: python, pyspark, conda, azure-machine-learning-service

How to install and use **MMLSpark** on a local machine with Intel Python 3.6?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
            .config("spark.jars.packages", "Azure:mmlspark:0.13") \
            .getOrCreate()

import mmlspark
from mmlspark import TrainClassifier
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from mmlspark import ComputeModelStatistics, TrainedClassifierModel


dataFilePath = "AdultCensusIncome.csv"
import os, urllib
if not os.path.isfile(dataFilePath):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/datasets/" + dataFilePath, dataFilePath)
data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv(dataFilePath, dtype={" hours-per-week": np.float64}))
data = data.select([" education", " marital-status", " hours-per-week", " income"])
train, test = data.randomSplit([0.75, 0.25], seed=123)
train.limit(10).toPandas()

model = TrainClassifier(model=LogisticRegression(), labelCol=" income", numFeatures=256).fit(train)
prediction = model.transform(test)
metrics = ComputeModelStatistics().transform(prediction)
metrics.limit(10).toPandas()
```

MMLSpark does not work. Could someone help with this issue?

Comment: "MMLSPARK does not work" is not really describing what is your problem. maybe you could add some more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't describe problem correctly, but if you are looking for installation commands. then please see below,

install pyspark first.

```
pip install pyspark
```

To install MMLSpark on an existing HDInsight Spark Cluster, you can execute a script action on the cluster head and worker nodes. For instructions on running script actions, see this guide.

The script action url is: https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/buildartifacts/0.13/install-mmlspark.sh.

If you're using the Azure Portal to run the script action, go to Script actions → Submit new in the Overview section of your cluster blade. In the Bash script URI field, input the script action URL provided above. Mark the rest of the options as shown on the screenshot to the right.

Submit, and the cluster should finish configuring within 10 minutes or so.

from Original Docs:- 
https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark

Comment: OK. It is not possible run mmlspark on a local machine, just on Azure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlexandreMigueldeCarvalho, that is simply not true. I know this question is old, but I've just stumbled upon it. I will post how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question (and very ill-posed by the way), some people may still benefit.

In order to make a local Spark environment work with mmlspark, you must set the env variable `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`. Since I am working with Jupyter, I find it useful to set env variables via the script `~/.jupyter/jupyter-env.sh` (or `/etc/profile.d/jupyter-env.sh` if you are in a AWS EC2 instance). The env variable itself should be:

```sh
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--packages com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5 --repositories https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven pyspark-shell'
```

Note that we also have to freeze `org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5` to a version that works with mmlspark. Feel free to test with others.

The full `jupyter-env.sh` script that works for me is:

```sh
export SPARK_HOME=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2,com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5 --repositories https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven pyspark-shell'
```

It should be kind of obvious that you must change `SPARK_HOME` (line 1) to point to where your spark dir is located. Also, note that I choose to set my hadoop version in `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`, you should check which version you have installed.

I hope it helps other people, as it took me a while to figure this out.
Cheers